# How to animate a manager to expand when it receives focus in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

In my app, I am using a manager whose height is controlled by using its `sublayout()` method. Now when this manager(or any of the fields inside it) receives focus, I am able to increase the manager's height all at once, but i want to make it animate and gradually increase its height. How shall i achieve this?

I am developing for OS 5.0 and above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the timer in the paint method and expand its height every X milliseconds...

Comment: i want to expand the manager when its `onFocus()` is called, not every X milliseconds.

Comment: Can you post some sample code relating to your idea? Perhaps that could help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe the idea is when `onFocus()` happens, you would kick off a timer that repaints your manager every X milliseconds and in that repainting logic, it would increase the size of the manager by some small amount on each iteration until it reaches the desired size.